# A line segment with a length of 24 makes a 90-degree angle with one of the legs of an isosceles trapezoid. What is the area of this Trapezoid?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, quadrilateral

[image]

> Given that $ABCD$ is an isosceles trapezoid and that $|EB|=24$, $|EC|=26$, and m(EBC)=$90^o$. Find $A(ABCD)= ?$

From the pythagorean theorem, I can find that $|BC|=|AD|=10$. Then, I can find the area of the triangle $EBC$. But after this point, I can't progress any further. How do I find the area of this trapezoid?

Comment: ABCD does not look very isosceles in the image ...

Comment: Oh, Sorry, I didn't notice when I drew it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Option 1.** Consider the isosceles trapezoid with $BE=BD$ as diagonal:

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

We find:
$$BF=\frac{2S_{\Delta BCD}}{CD}=\frac{240}{26}=\frac{120}{13};\\
CF=\sqrt{BC^2-BF^2}=\sqrt{100-\frac{120^2}{13^2}}=\frac{50}{13};\\
S_{ABCD}=\frac{AB+CD}{2}\cdot BF=\frac{(26-2\cdot CF)+26}{2}\cdot \frac{120}{13}=\\
=\frac{34560}{169}\approx \color{red}{204.5}.\\
$$

**Option 2.** Consider the point $E$ as a midpoint:

$\hspace{3cm}$[image: ![enter image description here]

We find:
$$EH=\sqrt{BE^2+BH^2}=\sqrt{24^2+5^2}=\sqrt{601};\\
BI=\frac{2S_{\Delta BEH}}{EH}=\frac{2\cdot 60}{\sqrt{601}};\\
S_{ABCD}=EH\cdot BF=\sqrt{601}\cdot \frac{4\cdot 60}{\sqrt{601}}=\color{red}{240}.$$

Conclusion: The trapezoid is not unique.

Comment: Interesting that the area in option 2 is exactly the same as when we take $A=E$. Perhaps that is what misled the problem setter?

Comment: Perhaps, the setter considered the two extreme cases and concluded. Though, the option 1 was the extreme.

Comment: x @farruhota: But the extreme cases are $204.5$ and $240$. He would need to have considered _one_ extreme and one in-the-middle case. (In your option 2, if we cut off triangle DEG and put it next to AE instead, we get a parallelogram that is obviously twice the area of BEC; the setter may have mistakenly thought that this generalizes).

Comment: Yes, he must have thought he checked the two extreme cases (top corner and middle), both giving $240$ whereas the real extreme was the bottom corner. Perhaps, the OP can gather feedback and communicate his thoughts here.

Comment: x @farruhota: Ah yes, on further thought that's probably a valid sense of "extreme" too.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: Which property of a trapezoid does a rectangle fail to have?

Comment: @farruhota This was a problem from a high school geometry textbook. It was given in the properties section that when $E$ is the middle point the area of the triangle is half of the trapezoid's. Indeed, I believe that is where problem setter made a mistake by not mentioning that $AE=ED$. Thanks for the answer, by the way.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: Not in my use of the word. That way to define things would also imply that a square is not a rectangle, that a rhombus is not a parallelogram, and similar nonsense.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoid) it states "at least one pair of parallel sides" and shows special types of trapezoids that are parallelograms, rectangles, rhombi and squares.

Answer (score 4):

The triangle $BCE$ is uniqely determined, but other points $D$ and $A$ are not so this trapezoid does not have fixed area, it depend on $A$ (and then is $D$ determined also).

Comment: If $|BCE|$ is fixed, then doesn't this fix A and D, too? Can you elaborate on your answer, please?

Comment: Note that the trapezoid is isosceles.

Comment: Try to play in some aplet, say Geogebra. You can move $AD$ through $E$ and you will see you don't get a single trapezoid.

Comment: How does that affect? @Arthur

Comment: Right, move $E$ to $D$ and adjust $AD$ to form an isosceles trapezoid. In other words, one option is to make $BE$ a diagonal of the isosceles trapezoid.

Comment: $|BD|=|AD|=10$, So I can't move any side

Comment: You can tilt the sides. Change the $BCD$ angle.

Comment: Just draw $D$ arbitrary, and reflect $BC$ across perpendicular bisector of $CD$. And now move $D$....

Comment: I tried it, but as I moved D right or left, it changes the value of $|BE|$ and $|EC|$

Comment: No first draw BCE which must be fixed

Comment: @greedoid thanks for the help. I could draw the figure

Answer (score 4):

As a concrete example of how the figure is not determined:

- One option is that $A$ and $E$ coincide, and $ABCD$ is a rectangle of area $24\cdot 10=240$.
- Another option is that $E$ and $D$ coincide, in which case the area of the trapezoid is $\frac{10\cdot 24}{26}(26-\frac{10\cdot 10}{26}) \approx 204$.

Comment: thanks for the answer. can you explain what do you mean by coincide,please? The answer is indeed 240

Comment: @EldarRahimli: "Coincide" means that $A$ and $E$ are the same point, so EC is simply the diagonal of the rectangle. It is true that $240$ is _one possible_ answer, but based on the conditions you have disclosed it is not the _only possible_ answer.